# AD attribute names in other languages

Tags: .net, windows, active-directory

In my English AD I would write a query to filter on eg. objectClass. If I had to write a query against eg. a Spanish AD would it still be objectClass or do the attribute names themselves also change when the AD installation is in another language?

Answer (score 1):

[Thanks to the guys on the MS forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d709dec7-619b-431a-a7a8-bbdf9012030c/ad-attribute-names-in-other-languages?forum=winserverDS) - attribute names and class names are not translated